Mars paraterraforming (worldhouse) vs. full terraforming
Ok I had a thought I wasn't sure how to figure it out. If you enclosed Mars in a worldhouse (ie. planetary shell) are there enough volatiles (gases) to make a breathable atmosphere for the whole planet without importing? I mean if people are already living there you may not want to smash Kuiper belt objects (comets) into the planet to build one and you are building a planet shell around the thing anyway. I think that would be too destructive.

No, there isn't enough of the right gases to increase the pressure.
With a surface pressure of 0.00628 atm, you would need to squeeze the current atmosphere 160 times to increase its pressure to 1 atm.
But even doing so you would get 96% of CO2 and only 0.15% of Oxygen, which is all but a breathable atmosphere.

Thanks I know the mix wasn't correct but I wondered how much could be enclosed without importing gas. I'm sure the current co2 could be broken down into o2 and co to get the oxygen.

If you were filling a world-spanning habitat, much of the surface area could only have meters or tens of meters of height. It doesn't seem out of the question to achieve that 160x ratio. The composition is a bigger problem, but one partial workaround is that you could relax the "breathable" requirement for agricultural areas. If you want a substantial world-spanning biosphere though, you're going to need more nitrogen.

you don't need 1atm for a breathable athmosphere. especially if you have a high O2 partial pressure.

@ths there's an issue of comfort, and there is a somewhat higher fire hazard even with the same partial pressure due to the reduced thermal mass, but agricultural areas don't need an atmosphere that is comfortable for or even breathable to humans.

There are vast amounts of oxygen locked up in water ice and carbon dioxide on Mars. Enough water to cover the planet to a depth of 35m. Given sufficient energy this could be extracted by electrolysis of the water or by reduction of carbon dioxide or both so oxygen is not ultimately an issue. What is in short supply is nitrogen (and argon which may also be used as a diluent gas).
Mass of Martian atmosphere 2.5x10^16 kg
of which 2.6% is nitrogen and 1.9% is argon so 4.5% could be used as diluent gases
4.5% of 2.5 x 10^16 = 1.1 x 10^15 kg
Earth’s atmosphere is 79% diluent gas so multiply the available diluent gas on Mars by by 100/79 = 1.4 x 10^15 kg of potential atmosphere on Mars (in other words oxygenate the available diluent gases on Mars).
Earth’s air density at sea level is around 1.2kg/cubic metre so 1.4 x 10^15/1.2 = 1.2 x 10^15 cubic metres of sea level pressure Earth atmosphere equivalent could be produced on Mars. Assuming 10m ceiling (divide by 10) that would be 1.2x10^14 square metres
surface area of Mars = 1.4 x 10^14 square metres
So more or less the whole surface of Mars could be enclosed in pressure structures with sea level Earth atmosphere equivalent up to 10m deep.
Taller structures would limit coverage, lowering the air pressure would increase coverage. Food production areas could be at lower pressure and include a higher carbon dioxide level etc.
https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/marsfact.html

Overall a great answer, but nitrogen is more than just a diluent, and CO2 is more than just a filler.  Nitrogen cannot be easily substituted because it is a vital part of many macronutrients in organic chemistry.  Healthy soil includes symbiotic microbes that rely on the nitrogen in the air. Also, CO2 levels of greater than 1% are toxic to most plants.  So, you really need your agricultural areas to have an Earth like atmosphere.

Some agricultural plants do handle elevated CO2 levels well, nitrogen fixing is an energy-intensive process which likely is not limited by the concentration of nitrogen, and plants don't need nearly as high a concentration of oxygen.

@ChristopherJamesHuff "handling CO2 well" is the difference between tolerating 1% and 2% CO2 before it becomes toxic. Not the 78% it would take to use CO2 as a filter gas in place of nitrogen.  As for nitrogen fixation, it is an anerobic process.  It happens deep in the soil where air can just barely penetrate because oxygen breaks down the enzyme responsible for it.  The smaller your nitrogen to oxygen ratio, the narrower the band of soil depths you have where nitrogen fixing bacteria can get enough nitrogen and little enough oxygen to function.

Sorry I was off by an order of magnitude. It is 0.1-0.2%.  Not 1-2%

You'll need to melt a lot of rocks.
The atmosphere of Mars is very low on oxygen, but the the rocks are full of oxides. If you dome off the planet (or at least part of it), and then start melting rocks, they will release enough oxygen to meet human needs... but this does come with a few caveats.
Thermal decomposition is really inefficient, so why use it?
If your only goal is to extract oxygen from rocks, then yes it is.  You could electrolyze ice for or use a methane reduction method as pointed out in the comments, which could be more energy efficient if viewed as a stand-alone problem, but if you already making a giant glass dome, it means you are already mining and smelting trillions of tons of oxygen rich minerals.  While other methods are normally the preferred way of getting oxygen out of rocks, smelting the various minerals used for refining steel and glass both release significant amounts of oxygen as natural byproducts; so, you can simply collect your exhaust, separate out the unwanted CO2 and SO2, and you are left with enough waste O2 and H2O to fill your habitat dome(s) without having to dip into the planet's ice or methane reserves.
Nitrogen is going to pose a greater challenge
Mars has already lost most of its nitrogen meaning that creating a breathable atmosphere may actually be much easier than generating an atmosphere able to support an entire terrestrial ecosystem.
Nitrogen is more than just a filler ingredient in the Earth's atmosphere. While one of its functions is to limit the inflammability of a lower density, human breathable pure oxygen environment, its role becomes a lot more complex when you factor in agriculture. Nitrogen is a vital part of many macronutrients in organic chemistry and it enters the food chain via plant symbiotic microbes that absorb nitrogen from the air, and so, humans indirectly rely on the nitrogen in the air because we eat foods that both need and provide us with significant amounts of it.
You also have to be careful about any filler you try to replace Nitrogen with.  While you will have plenty of CO2 to work with, levels of greater than 0.1% at 1 atmosphere of density is toxic to most plants, and long term exposure to levels greater than 0.5% is toxic to humans.
It is possible, that if you drill down far enough into Mars that you will find significant sources of Ammonia which fixing bacteria can use directly as a nitrogen source, and overtime biological processes will release enough nitrogen into the air that you can stop adding more ammonia, and just let the microbes do thier job recycling it.  You'll have to plan this out carefully though as adding ammonia to your system will reduce you available oxygen and increase your water; so, you'll probably need massive reserve tanks for controlling the balance of different fluids in your environment until such point that an equilibrium is reached

Melting silica gets you molten silica, not silicon and oxygen...

Correction: you will need to electrolyze lots of rocks. Melting them does nothing useful.

There is enough water ice on Mars to cover the whole planet to a depth of 35 metres (assuming a level surface) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_on_Mars  so oxygen and hydrogen are not an issue but nitrogen is

@Hearth No you don't.  What you mean is that it is more energy efficient to  electrolyze lots of rocks, but O2 is already going a waste product of the smelting processes used to make both steel and glass... which you will need to already do to dome off the whole planet.  When collected as a waste product of the industrial processes you are already doing, it's actually becomes a more energy efficient method than eletrolisis.

@AlexP Sure, melting pure silica does not release oxygen (except at insanely high temperatures), but pure silica is not what you would be melting.  When you melt silica in the presence of other minerals like limestone, calcium carbonate, etc. you get Oxygen as a waste product.  Also, there are other common minerals on Mars like hematite which release oxygen when melted all on thier own.

@Nosajimiki: Heating calcium carbonate famously produces calcium oxide (= unslaked lime) and carbon dioxide, much to the chagrin of environmentalists worldwide; it decomposes long before melting. But yes, roasting hematite produces magnetite and oxygen; again, this happens long before melting.

A potential alternative to molten oxide electrolysis or thermal decomposition is reduction with methane or methane-derived carbon, with the CO2 byproduct being recycled via the Sabatier process, or reduction with CO produced via the water-gas shift reaction. With electrolysis of the water byproduct to recover the hydrogen, the ultimate waste product is oxygen.

Note that CO is also used in low-energy carbonyl processes for getting pure nickel and iron from impure metal, and methane is a reasonably high-performing rocket fuel and a useful starting point for a lot of organic chemistry, so producing these at very large scales as efficiently as possible is already going to be a major priority for Martian chemical industry.

@AlexP Sure, it makes since that that would be an intermediate step, and I did mention CO2 as one of the other byproduct gasses in glass making in my revised answer.

@ChristopherJamesHuff Sure, there are lots of ways to get Oxygen out of stuff.  My focus though was on thermal decomposition because the setting already requires that the Martians smelt trillions of tons of material to build the megastructure in question.  So, if that process is already making the needed Oxygen as a byproduct, no need to go out of your way to get it from other sources.
